# SQLite performance issue on new debian server

Tags: php, performance, sqlite, debian

I recently installed a new server with:

- debian squeeze
- apache2
- php5.3.3-7
- sqlite

When migrating my application from an older server I observed that it runs much slower.
I isolated the problem, sqlite updates runs more than 10 times slower.

Both sqlite are version 2.8.17, the older server runs PHP Version 5.2.6-1+lenny3
Here is the benchmark script I used:

```
function write($value) {
    $dbh = sqlite_open('mt.sq');
    $sql = "REPLACE INTO hash (key,value,lm) VALUES ('test','$value','dummy')";
    sqlite_query($dbh, $sql);
    $dbh = sqlite_close($dbh);
}

$n = 100;
$start = microtime(true);
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) write($i);
$avg = (microtime(true) - $start) / $n;
echo "Average write time: ".$avg."[s]";
```

New Server Results: Average write time: 0.0795[s]
Old Server Results: Average write time: 0.0032[s]

Here is the database for testing:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE hash(
    key PRIMARY KEY,
    value,
    lm
);
INSERT INTO hash VALUES('test',99,'dummy');
COMMIT;
```

I dont know where to search. Does anyone observe same performance problems?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are there any hardware differences between the machines?

Comment: what filesystem on debian ?

Comment: Old Server is:   
2 x Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E7200 @ 2.53GHz / 2Gb Ram / Ext3 / Debian 5.0.1  

New Server is: 4 x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1225 V2 @ 3.20GHz / 16Gb Ram / Ext4 / Debian 6.0.6

Using phpsysinfo, the new one seems to be 2.5 times faster (System Bogomips 25k vs 10k for the old one)

Comment: What are the file system mount options?

Comment: @CL. Not sure it's what you expect, here is the fstab of the old server: `/dev/md2       /var    ext3    defaults                0       2` and the one of the new one: `/dev/md2        /var    ext4    defaults,relatime       0       2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known "issue" - ext4 comes with barriers enabled by default (in contrast to ext3) - see [Serious performance issues with ext4fs barriers](http://liferea.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/serious-performance-issues-with-ext4fs.html):

> The important difference in this aspect from ext4fs to ext3fs is that **ext4fs comes with barriers enabled**, which is a filesystem feature (optional in ext3fs) that tries to improves filesystem integrity. But this comes at a cost: depending on your application use case this **might decrease filesystem throughput a lot**

Comment: I modified barrier=0 in fstab and now it works at a similar speed. I will learn about barriers before choosing if I keep it disabled or not. Thank you very much to all of you.